# For loop to get Sequence of number for n number of nodes

Tags: for-loop, xquery

If i'm having 'n' number of nodes and i want to assign a number from starting of the node to 'n' number of nodes.
example:

```
<entity>
  <result>
    <seq>1</seq>
  </result>
  <result>
    <seq>2</seq>
  </result>
  <result>
    <seq>3</seq>
  </result>
  ....
  ....
  ....
  <result>
    <seq>n</seq>
  </result>
</entity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the example is what you want as result, try this:

```
<entity>
    {
        for $n in 1 to 10
        return
            <result><seq>{$n}</seq></result>
    }
</entity>
```

Otherwise, rewrite your question so it contains

- What do you want to achieve
- What's the input
- What's the expected output

Also, do you want to update you document (XQuery Update) or only enrich the output?

Answer (score 1):

Use the at keyword to count the iteration.

```
let $list := (20, 23, 25, 24, 22, 21)

return
  <entity>
  {
    for $n at $seq in $list
      return
        <result><seq>{$seq}</seq><value>{$n}</value></result>
  }
  </entity>
```